# Error while running Rmd file but none when executing function directly

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have created an R function which uses a `tryCatch` construct to skip over errors. The function works when executed as a standalone but gives an error when executing within an `Rmarkdown` file

The code is as below

```
for(x in 1:length(aa)){
    bowlers <- unique(aa[[x]]$bowler)
    for (y in 1:length(bowlers)){
        #cat("x=",x,"team",theTeams[x],"\n")
        tryCatch(l <- getBowlerWicketDetails(team=theTeams[x],name=bowlers[y],dir="."),
                 error = function(e) {
                     print("Error!")

                 }

        )
        l <- select(l,bowler,wickets,economyRate)
        o <-rbind(o,l)

    }
}
```

I get the following error when executing the code within an `Rmd`. The error is

> Error in select_(.data,.dots=lazyeval::lazy_dots(...),:object l not found calls:Anonymos etc.

I think the code is trying to evaluate even when there is an error in the `getBowlerWicketDetails()` function when 'l' will not be available. How can this be resolved?

Comment: I suspect the function `getBowlerWicketDetails(team=theTeams[x],name=bowlers[y],dir=".")` , works in you current working dir because the dir are same maybe that is not the case in your Rmd file. Try with `dir = full_path_to_dir`  instead of `dir=.`

Comment: Ossnan - It did not help. Added full path.When I execute the command  separately in the markdown file, it goes  works but when executed as a markdown I get the error. A

Comment: Without a reproducible example, we can only speculate on likely issue(s). I suggest posting some dummy data using `dput(data)`

Comment: Maybe `{r, error=FALSE}` will help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the problem by adding an additional check exists(). As I mentioned, directly executing the function seemed to work while executing within Rmd gave the variable does not exist

The modified code was as follows

```
for(x in 1:length(aa)){
    bowlers <- unique(aa[[x]]$bowler)
    for (y in 1:length(bowlers)){
        #cat("x=",x,"team",theTeams[x],"\n")
        tryCatch(l <- getBowlerWicketDetails(team=theTeams[x],name=bowlers[y],dir="."),
                 error = function(e) {
                     #print("Error!")                         
                 }                     
        )
        if(exists("l")){            
           m <- select(l,bowler,wickets,economyRate)
           o <-rbind(o,m)
        }

    }
}
```

This worked finally for both.

Thanks all!